# why Route is not working with my react app?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop react application. The problem is when I use the Route and Switch, it is not working. Actually, nothing is happening. Could anyone please give me a clue about the possible problem here?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import DishDetailComponent from './DishdetailComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render() {
    const HomePage = () => {
      return(
        <Home />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" Component={HomePage} />  
            <Route path="/menu" Component={() => <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />} />
            <Redirect to="home" />
          </ Switch> 
        </Router>
      <Footer />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Describe nothing? What URL are you trying to view your app at? Even if the switch is not working you should still see your Header and Footer rendered.

Comment: You shoud use BrowserRouter into your index.js file wrapped around App component

Comment: nothing means that it ignores the route part and just shows the header and footer. the homepage (home component) includes a simple line in html.

Comment: it's fine. the query has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistake is that you have capitalized the "C" in the `component` prop, so you should call it like `component={HomePage}`

Here are some other things you could improve upon though:

If you are gonna use an inline function, it is preferable to use the `render` prop, and if you are gonna use a component directly, preferable to just use `Component` prop. Moreover:

```
const HomePage = () => {
      return(
        <Home />
      );
    }
```

is unnecessary as you can just use the `Home` component directly.

Try this for your `render()` function:

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />  
            <Route path="/menu" render={() => <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />} />
            <Redirect to="home" />
          </ Switch> 
        </Router>
      <Footer />

      </div>
    );
  }
```